# How does webpack handle different versions of the same dependency in a monorepo?

Tags: webpack, monorepo, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I created four fake monorepos with two packages each:
<sup>*Lerna v3 • Node.js 12.20 • Yarn 1.19.1*</sup>

- Package `foo1` imports `foo2`
- Both `foo1` and `foo2` use the same library (Ramda)
- Both `foo1` and `foo2` are bundled with webpack

Both `foo1` and `foo2` as well as Ramda are ES modules.

The key differences between these monorepos are the versions of Ramda and [whether dependencies are hoisted or not.](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/)

After bootstrapping each monorepo I looked at the size of the bundle for the `foo1` package:

| `foo1` Ramda | `foo2` Ramda | dependencies hoisted? | `foo1` bundle size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.26.0 | 0.26.0 | Yes | 92K |
| 0.26.0 | 0.26.0 | No | 92K |
| 0.26.0 | 0.25.0 | Yes | 91K |
| 0.26.0 | 0.25.0 | No | 91K |

I was expecting the size of the last two bundles to be significantly bigger but they are not. **Why?**